# Recuperar/localizar objeto em arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Estou fazendo um pequeno CRUD com o tema poupança para fins de estudo. Criei 3 classes: Poupanca, Contas e Tela (UI Swing).

Na tela eu efetuo o cadastro de uma conta com os atributos nome, agência, número de conta (o saldo inicia com valor 0 por padrão), conforme o construtor.

**O problema:** não consigo recuperar os dados nos métodos consultar ou remover conta por exemplo. Ou retorna o próprio nome inserido na UI na hora da pesquisa ou não retorna nada.

**O que eu preciso:** Digitar o atributo nome do titular de uma conta Poupanca(objeto) e pelo nome o sistema fazer uma busca no **ArrayList contas**. Se encontrar o nome, retornar o objeto (a conta) que tem esse nome como atributo (e apresentar os dados dessa conta na TextArea), caso contrário retornar nulo.

**obs:** o método consultar 2 é outra tentativa de consulta. Mas acredito que o erro está na classe main (Tela.java). Tenho a impressão que tem algo errado nos métodos dos botões, mas não consegui resolver. Tentei criar o objeto no escopo da classe, tentei criar direto no escopo dos métodos dos botões, etc...nada da certo.

Classe Poupanca.java

```
package classes;

public class Poupanca {

    private String nome;
    private String Agencia;
    private String Conta;
    private double saldo;

    public Poupanca(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Poupanca(String nome, String Agencia, String Conta, double saldo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.Agencia = Agencia;
        this.Conta = Conta;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public void sacarDinheiro(double valor) throws Exception {
        if (valor > this.saldo) {
            throw new Exception("Saldo insuficiente");
        }
        this.saldo -= valor;
    }

    public void depositarDinheiro(double valor) throws Exception {
        if (valor <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("Não é possível deposito nulo ou negativo.");
        }
        this.saldo += valor;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getAgencia() {
        return Agencia;
    }

    public void setAgencia(String Agencia) {
        this.Agencia = Agencia;
    }

    public String getConta() {
        return Conta;
    }

    public void setConta(String Conta) {
        this.Conta = Conta;
    }

}
```

Classe Contas.java

```
package classes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Contas {

    private ArrayList<Poupanca> contas = new ArrayList();

    public void cadastrarConta(Poupanca poup) {
        contas.add(poup);
    }

    public Poupanca consultarConta(Poupanca poup) {
        int posicao = contas.indexOf(poup);
        if (posicao >= 0) {
            return contas.get(posicao);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Poupanca consultar2(String nome) {
        Iterator<Poupanca> it = contas.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Poupanca contato = it.next();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removerConta(Poupanca poup) {
        int posicao = contas.indexOf(poup);
        contas.remove(posicao);
    }

    public String numeroDeContas() { //apenas para curiosidade, mostra a quantidade de contas cadastradas a cada inserção efetivada
        return contas.size() + "";
    }

}
```

Classe Tela.java completa:

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import classes.Poupanca;
import classes.Contas;

public class Tela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String nome = "";
    String agencia = "";
    String conta = "";
    String valorOperacao = "";
    Contas contas = new Contas();
    Poupanca poup;

    public Tela() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tfNome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tfAgencia = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tfConta = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        botaoCadastrarConta = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        botaoConsultarConta = new javax.swing.JButton();
        botaoExcluirConta = new javax.swing.JButton();
        botaoDepositar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        botaoSacar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tfValorOperacao = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        labelTotalContas = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        taSaida = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("P O U P A N C A 1.0");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("POUPANÇA");

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Nome:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Agência:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Conta:");

        botaoCadastrarConta.setText("Cadastrar Conta");
        botaoCadastrarConta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoCadastrarContaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        botaoConsultarConta.setText("Consultar Conta");
        botaoConsultarConta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoConsultarContaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        botaoExcluirConta.setText("Excluir Conta");
        botaoExcluirConta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoExcluirContaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        botaoDepositar.setText("Depositar");
        botaoDepositar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoDepositarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        botaoSacar.setText("Sacar");

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Valor da Operação:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(tfValorOperacao, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(tfValorOperacao, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(botaoCadastrarConta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(botaoConsultarConta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(botaoExcluirConta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(tfAgencia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(tfConta))
                            .addComponent(tfNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 326, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(botaoDepositar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                        .addComponent(botaoSacar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(tfNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(tfAgencia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(tfConta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(botaoConsultarConta)
                    .addComponent(botaoCadastrarConta)
                    .addComponent(botaoExcluirConta)
                    .addComponent(botaoDepositar)
                    .addComponent(botaoSacar))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        labelTotalContas.setText("Contas Cadastradas: 0");

        taSaida.setEditable(false);
        taSaida.setColumns(20);
        taSaida.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(taSaida);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addGap(238, 238, 238))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(labelTotalContas)
                                .addContainerGap())))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 124, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(labelTotalContas)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void botaoCadastrarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

            nome = tfNome.getText();
            agencia = tfAgencia.getText();
            conta = tfConta.getText();

            contas.cadastrarConta(poup = new Poupanca(nome, agencia, conta, 0));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Conta Cadastrada com sucesso!", "Parabéns!", HEIGHT);

            labelTotalContas.setText("Contas Cadastradas: " + contas.numeroDeContas());

            String limpa = "";
        tfNome.setText(limpa);
        tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
        tfConta.setText(limpa);

    }                                                   

    private void botaoConsultarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

//        try {
            nome = tfNome.getText();

            contas.consultarPorNome(nome);

            taSaida.setText("Nome: " + poup.getNome() + "\nAgência: " + poup.getAgencia() + "\nConta: " + poup.getConta() + "\nSaldo: "
                    + poup.getSaldo());

//        } catch (Exception E) {
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Campo nome não pode ficar vazio!", E.getMessage(), 2);
//        }

        String limpa = "";
        tfNome.setText(limpa);
        tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
        tfConta.setText(limpa);

    }                                                   

    private void botaoExcluirContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

        nome = tfNome.getText();
        Poupanca poup = new Poupanca(nome);
        contas.removerConta(poup);

        String limpa = "";
        tfNome.setText(limpa);
        tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
        tfConta.setText(limpa);
        taSaida.setText(limpa);
    }                                                 

    private void botaoDepositarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage(), "ATENÇÃO!", 2);
        }

    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tela().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton botaoCadastrarConta;
    private javax.swing.JButton botaoConsultarConta;
    private javax.swing.JButton botaoDepositar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botaoExcluirConta;
    private javax.swing.JButton botaoSacar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelTotalContas;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea taSaida;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfAgencia;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfConta;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfNome;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfValorOperacao;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

A interface gráfica: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem organizada sua pergunta, parabéns, isso ajuda e muito a comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

### Classe Contas

```
public Poupanca consultarPorNome(String nome) {

        /* Essa linha abaixo é legal utilizar, pois você usa Lambda e é uma coisa nova
         * já que você esta aprendendo, porém, só da para utilizar com Java acima da Versão 8.
         * 
         * return contas.stream().filter(x -> x.getNome().equals(nome)).findFirst().get();*/

        // Se não for uma versão igual ou acima da 8, você pode fazer o famoso Foreach
        for(Poupanca poupanca : contas) {
            if(poupanca.getNome().equals(nome)){
               return poupanca; 
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

### Classe Tela

```
    private void botaoConsultarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        nome = tfNome.getText();

        Poupanca contaDoUsuario = contas.consultarPorNome(nome);
        if (contaDoUsuario != null) {

            taSaida.setText("Nome: " + contaDoUsuario.getNome() + "\nAgência: " + contaDoUsuario.getAgencia() + "\nConta: "
                    + contaDoUsuario.getConta() + "\nSaldo: " + contaDoUsuario.getSaldo());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Não existe uma conta para esse nome");
        }

        String limpa = "";
        tfNome.setText(limpa);
        tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
        tfConta.setText(limpa);
    } // Continue usando o seu Try Catch, só queria representar a validação do caso "null" para poupança
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o método de busca por nome da seguinte forma:

```
public Poupanca consultarPorNome(String nome) {

    for(Poupanca p : contas) {
        if(p.getNome().equals(nome)){
           return p; 
        }
    }
    return null;
```

O método receberá o nome em forma de string e dentro do loop sobre a lista de contas, verificamos se alguma conta possui aquele nome. Quando for encontrado, retornamos a conta e interrompemos o loop.

Para usar, basta invocar este método no botão onde você chama a pesquisa por nome na sua tela:

```
private void botaoConsultarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try {
        nome = tfNome.getText();
        this.poup = contas.consultarPorNome(nome);
        taSaida.setText("Nome: " + poup.getNome() + "\nAgência: " + poup.getAgencia() + "\nConta: "
                + poup.getConta() + "\nSaldo: " + poup.getSaldo());
    } catch (Exception E) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Campo nome não pode ficar vazio!", E.getMessage(), 2);
    }

    String limpa = "";
    tfNome.setText(limpa);
    tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
    tfConta.setText(limpa);
}
```

Seu código tem muitos problemas como essa variável `poup` que não tem necessidade de ser de classe, mas apenas local, e outros problemas de operações sem tratamento que irão estourar exceção mas não entrarei em detalhes para não desvirtuar a resposta.

Comment: Muito boa e muito bem explicada +1

Answer (score 0):

Que bom que gostaram da forma que expus a pergunta. Organização é essencial na vida. Vi os vários erros Articuno, deixei pro final, porque primeiro queria fazer o programa funcionar. Deu certo as dicas suas e do Ricardo. Muito obrigado.

Vou colocar como ficou os métodos dos botões "cadastrar" e "consultar" funcionando se alguém tiver uma dúvida parecida:

Botão cadastrar

```
 private void botaoCadastrarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        try {
            nome = tfNome.getText();
            agencia = tfAgencia.getText();
            conta = tfConta.getText();

            Poupanca poup = new Poupanca(nome, agencia, conta, 0);

            contas.cadastrarConta(poup);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Conta cadastrada com sucesso!", "Parabéns!", 1);

            labelTotalContas.setText("Contas Cadastradas: " + contas.numeroDeContas());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage(), "ERRO!", 2);
        }

        String limpa = "";
        tfNome.setText(limpa);
        tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
        tfConta.setText(limpa);

    }
```

Botão consultar

```
private void botaoConsultarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

        try {

            nome = tfNome.getText();
            Poupanca poup = new Poupanca(nome);

            poup = contas.consultarPorNome(nome);

            taSaida.setText("Nome: " + poup.getNome() + "\nAgência: " + poup.getAgencia() + "\nConta: " + poup.getConta() + "\nSaldo: "
                    + poup.getSaldo());

        } catch (Exception E) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, E.getMessage(), "ERRO!", 2);
        }

        String limpa = "";
        tfNome.setText(limpa);
        tfAgencia.setText(limpa);
        tfConta.setText(limpa);

    }
```

Comment: Ainda continua com alguns problemas estruturais que eu não faria, como estes métodos fazem praticamente a mesma coisa com uma leve diferença e você criou dois listeners diferentes pra eles. Enfim, bons estudos :)